# Yii2 Mpdf - _MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS does not work after upgrade

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I have reinstalled my Yii2 application using newest server stack from Bitnami. But there is one remaining issue that I cannot resolve in any way.

Mpdf does not see my custom fonts despite having defined this before Pdf instantiation:
`define("_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", Yii::getAlias('@webroot/fonts/'));`

I am getting this error:

```
2020-11-28 15:29:08 [5.173.161.70][-][is46fr5fu08dvg8lthf00obqio][error][Mpdf\MpdfException:1] Mpdf\MpdfException: Cannot find TTF TrueType font file "Roboto-Regular.ttf" in configured font directories. in /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Fonts/FontFileFinder.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(3861): Mpdf\Fonts\FontFileFinder->findFontFile()
#1 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(4154): Mpdf\Mpdf->AddFont()
#2 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(10875): Mpdf\Mpdf->SetFont()
#3 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php(1483): Mpdf\Mpdf->SetDefaultFont()
#4 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/Pdf.php(271): Mpdf\Mpdf->__construct()
#5 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/Pdf.php(247): kartik\mpdf\Pdf->setApi()
#6 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/Pdf.php(359): kartik\mpdf\Pdf->getApi()
#7 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/Pdf.php(236): kartik\mpdf\Pdf->output()
#8 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/common/models/Report.php(208): kartik\mpdf\Pdf->render()
#9 /opt/bitnami/hrpanel2/frontend/modules/urzad/controllers/ReportController.php(54): common\models\Report->download()
```

I have also tried stating absolute path instead of @webroot but it did not change anything.

I suppose this has stopped working because of the updated components, but I cannot figure out how to correct this. Any hints will be appreciated.

Here is my composer.json:

```
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Application Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "application template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "lajax/yii2-translate-manager": "1.*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
    "mongosoft/yii2-soap-server": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "~1.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-switchinput": "*",
    "philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar":"*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.0.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
            "tuyakhov/yii2-youtube": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
    "lajax/yii2-translate-manager": "1.*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
    "mongosoft/yii2-soap-server": "*",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "~2.0.0",
    "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget" : "~1.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-switchinput": "*",
    "philippfrenzel/yii2fullcalendar":"*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.0.0",
    "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
            "tuyakhov/yii2-youtube": "*"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

Here is complete code of the function with Pdf definition:

```
    define("_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", Yii::getAlias('@webroot/fonts/'));

    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;

    $content = Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial($view, $data);
    $header = Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial($headerView, $data);
    $cssInline = file_get_contents(Yii::getAlias('@webroot/source/css/report.css'));

    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'destination' => $destination,
        'content' => $content,
        'cssInline' => $cssInline,
        'cssFile' => Yii::getAlias('@webroot/source/css/common_rep.css'),
        'defaultFont' => 'roboto',
        'marginTop' => isset($margins[0]) ? $margins[0] : '',
        'marginRight' =>  isset($margins[1]) ? $margins[1] : '',
        'marginBottom' =>  isset($margins[2]) ? $margins[2] : '',
        'marginLeft' =>  isset($margins[3]) ? $margins[3] : '',
        'marginHeader' => isset($margins[4]) ? $margins[4] : '',
        'options' => [
            'title' => $this->getDocTitle(),
            'img_dpi' => 300,
            'debug' => true,
            'fontdata' => [
                "dejavusanscondensed" => [
                    'R' => "Roboto-Regular.ttf",
                    'I' => "Roboto-Regular.ttf",
                    'B' => "Roboto-Bold.ttf",
                ],
            ]
        ],
        'methods' => [
            'SetHTMLHeader' => [$header],
            'setHTMLFooter'=>['<table width="100%"><tr><td width="25%"></td><td width="50%" align="center"><img src="/img/logo-grey.png"/></td><td width="25%" align="right" valign="bottom">{PAGENO}</td></tr></table>'],
        ]
    ]);

    $pdf->filename = $this->getDocFilename(). '.pdf';
    return $pdf->render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency of `kartik-v/yii2-mpdf` without a constraint installed the last mPDF version 8.x which handles fonts differently.

Quick solution: change your composer constraint to `"kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "1.0.1"` and do a composer update, which will install mPDF 6.x where `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS` still works.

---

If you need newer PHP support, first change your PHP needs in your composer.json file - that will rule out a few potentialy non-compatible libraries on composer update.

Then install the last version of `kartik-v/yii2-mpdf` (also with an upper version bound) and set up its `options` key like this:

```
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$pdf = new Pdf([
        ...
        'options' => [
            ...
            'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
                Yii::getAlias('@webroot/fonts/'),
            ]),
            'fontdata' => array_merge($fontData, [
                 "dejavusanscondensed" => [
                     'R' => "Roboto-Regular.ttf",
                     'I' => "Roboto-Regular.ttf",
                     'B' => "Roboto-Bold.ttf",
                  ],
            ]),
            'default_font' => 'dejavusanscondensed'
        ],
        ...
    ]);
```

Maybe name the font "roboto" correctly to prevent confusion in the future.

Consult the documentation for further details. https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html

---

Generally, you don't want to have asterisks `*` as constraints in your composer.json. Always include upper bound to prevent these changes in behaviour.

Comment: Ahhh! It sounded like a perfect answer... Until I found out that mPDF 6.x is incompatible with PHP 7.4.9. I am using the latest bitnami stack and would not like to downgrade PHP.
I will keep looking how to set up mPDF 8.x. If there is any instruction that you could point me at it will be appreciated.
I upvoted - the answer seems likr a great info for anyone who runs into this issue. Thanks, @Finve!

Comment: Fantastic! This works perfectly. I am working with an old app written by sbd else. I can imagine some stuff should be fixed but it's a bit risky to change things that work. I needed to adjust the referencing to `\Mpdf\Config\FontVariables` to work plus update css paths for some reason, but all in all this is a success. Great thanks, @Finwe.

Comment: Glad to help, mark the answer as accepted, please.